# Rails: Render collection partial: Getting size of collection inside partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection of items I want to render with a partial:

```
@items = ['a','b','c']

<%= render :collection => @items, :partial => 'item' %>
```

and I want to number the elements with *ascending numbers*. So the output should be:

```
3: a
2: b
1: c
```

I know rails provides a counter inside the partial, so if I wanted to number the items *descending*, I could create the following partial:

```
<%= item_counter %>: <%= item %>
```

which gives me

```
1: a
2: b
3: c
```

But for the *ascending* numbers, I need the total number of items, which I could provide with a local to the partial:

```
<%= render :collection => @items, :partial => 'item', :locals => {:total => @items.size} %>
```

and then in the partial:

```
<%= total - item_counter %>: <%= item %>
```

But it feels to me like repetition, because the render method already knows about the size of the collection.

**Is there really no way to get the total number of items of a collection inside a partial except using a local variable?**

Comment: No. [See for yourself](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb)

Comment: I looked there, but I thought I was missing something.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following is possible **since Rails Version 4.2**:

Inside the partial you have access to a function/variable called `collection_iteration`. Calling `collection_iteration.size` will give you the total.

From the [changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/actionview/CHANGELOG.md):

> The iteration object is available as the local variable
>   `#{template_name}_iteration` when rendering partials with collections.
>
> It gives access to the `size` of the collection being iterated over, the
>   current `index` and two convenience methods `first?` and `last?`.

Comment: No, there is no `collection` available in the partial. At least not in Rails 3.2.6. Where did you get this information?

Comment: I got this from the source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6b8dd70083d747535cc35dce176e5afb6ad98177/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb#L220

Comment: I also tested on my work application before posting the answer. I might check its Rails version on Tuesday, but it DOES work.

Comment: Would be great if this works, but I couldn't figure out how, yet.

Comment: Are you using a "native" collection partial or a partial you created yourself? In my test all I did was `<%= render @services %>` and the `collection` method was inside the `app/views/services/_service.html.erb` partial. Also, did you try a function with the partial name pluralized (like services or items)?

Comment: I created the partial myself. I tried all that without success. I loaded up a demo app here: https://github.com/SKoschnicke/partial-test View: https://github.com/SKoschnicke/partial-test/blob/master/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb Partial: https://github.com/SKoschnicke/partial-test/blob/master/app/views/things/_thing.html.erb (uncommenting any expression in the partial gives an error).

Comment: Just checked, my work application uses Rails 3.1.3. I'm looking at it, I want to know how to do it in new versions of rails too. I'll ping the thread when/if I find the answer.

Comment: It turns out it wasn't implemented, and the `collection` method was from Inherited Resources. [I implemented it and made a pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8342) but [there is another pull request that implements this and more](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7698).

Comment: Wow, I thought about implementing it as a gem but a change to rails is even better! Thanks for putting so much efford in this. Maybe you could create a second answer or edit your first one pointing to the pull request so I can accept is as a solution?

Comment: would you create a new answer to this question with the updated info? I really want to give you credit but I also want to add a correct answer to this question and would answer it by myself if you don't want to.

Comment: It seems that the pull request is still not merged, but scheduled for Rails 4.2.0: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7698

Answer (score 1):

Ah. Wanted to answer the question. But found correct answer. Anyway here is a tip on future. You can investigate the Rails mechanism with Ruby metaprogramming. For example by calling method 'Kernel#local_variables' in a view which in my case outputs:

```
[0] = :local_assigns
[1] = :output_buffer
[2] = :row
[3] = :row_counter
[4] = :row_iteration
[5] = :highlighted_description
[6] = :source_description
```

in case of

```
  <%= render partial: 'card', collection: @offers, as: :row %>
```

Answer (score 1):

For recent versions of Rails, like **Rails 7**, if you're rendering a partial like this:

```
render @items
```

Then inside the partial you should have access to the `item_iteration` and get the total size with `item_iteration.size`. You should also have access to `item_counter`, which is the current index.