# Using the same partial for lists and detail view, how to differentiate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm using the same partial to list blog items and show the complete item. The thing is that the detail view doesn't need to contain the link in the blog-image and the blog-title. What's best practice is this case?

I thought of checking a local variable which determines if the detail view is called, but somehow I can't get this to work:

call:

`render @post, locals: {detail: 'true'}`

Partial:

`link_to post.title, post if not defined? detail`

But somehow the local variable doesn't get passed to the partial.

EDIT:

Ok, I'm a bit further now:

```
#index.html.haml
= render @posts

#show.html.haml
= render @post

#post/_post.html.haml
= post_counter
```

Edit 2: Okay, solved it... was a bit of a headache that nested if statements in haml require complete parenthesis

```
#post/_post.html.haml
.blog-post
  .blog-post-image
    = (defined? post_counter) ? link_to(image_tag(post.cover_image(:large)), post) : image_tag(post.cover_image(:large))
```

Comment: please post complete partial and bothc alls

Answer (score 2):

I'd do the following:

```
#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<%= render "post", collection: @posts %>

#app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<%= render @post %>

#app/views/posts/_post.html.erb
<%= collection ? link_to(post.title, post) : post.title %>
<%= post.body unless collection %>
```

I got the `collection` var from this SO post:

[Rails: Render collection partial: Getting size of collection inside partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397848/rails-render-collection-partial-getting-size-of-collection-inside-partial)

You also have `[partial_name]_counter` as a local var if you wanted to track the index of your collection partials.

--

As per the updated question:

> The answer was to use `post_counter`:
>
> ```
> .blog-post
>   .blog-post-image
>     = (defined? post_counter) ? link_to(image_tag(post.cover_image(:large)), post) : image_tag(post.cover_image(:large))
> ```

Comment: I get an error that collection isn't a valid mathod or variable... are you sure that really exists? Would be a perfect solution.

Comment: It's apparently in the Rails 4.2 stable source. Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Let me check this out. It would be epic if it was the case

Comment: Works for me on Rails 2.4 - we have to assign the `collection` var, I'll update

Comment: somehow the "as: :post" part doesn't work for me, since I get an error "unknown method or variable post"

Comment: See what happens when you remove it, it works for me when I declare `as:`

Comment: If I do this, I get the "no method or variable error", even for a simple <%= post.title %>

Comment: The post_counter is probably the best bet, since it is either containing a count for the nth time the partial was parsed, or it is non-existent when only a single item is passen to render. What's the best way to check the existence of a var without causing an error?

Comment: The best way to check the existence of a var is probably to do `if @var` - that's how I do it

Comment: If you'd edit your reply to include my usage of post_counter, I'll mark your answer as the solution!

Comment: bo-oz - you ask a question and you got an answer. no need to redit to your needs to get a correct answer. thats dumbass behaviour

Answer (score 0):

That might be not the best approach, but you can pass varaibles(locals) into template-partials. (as you did).

Your effort was good, but `render @post` is rails magic and will ignore the locals.

should work both ways

```
-@post.each do |post|
  render partial "post", locals: {detail: true}
```

or

```
render partial "post", collection: @posts, as: post, locals: {detail: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just check the params hash

```
link_to post.title, post if params[:action] == "index"
```

If you use it elsewhere too you might want to check the controller too

```
link_to post.title, post if params[:action] == "index" && params[:controller] == "posts"
```

Comment: don't know. some people are just stupid. yours is also a legit method, but u could use action_name and controller_name ;)

Comment: @huanson didn't know about that, can you do that from the view?

Comment: of course, why not? and if not, make it accessible ;)

Answer (score 0):

For rendering single post:

```
<%= render @post %>
```

for rendering collection of posts:

```
render partial "post", collection: @posts, as: post, locals: { detail: true }
```

In your `_post` partial add the following line in the beginning:

```
<% detail ||= false %>
```

Now you have `detail` parameter initialized. No need for `defined?` function:

```
<% unless detail %>
  <%= link_to post.title, post %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to pass the detail as false on the show, rather than having `detail ||= false` in the view?

Comment: @japed isn't it better just write `<%= render @post %>`?

Comment: Personal preference I suppose, but I'm not a fan of assigning variables in the view.